# How to use camera2 with detect barcode

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, android-camera2

Camera is now deprecated and the recommend is to use camera2, can some one guide me to have any idea how to use camera2 with detect barcode

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities here

1. Create the barcode scanner from scratch (which is complicated)
2. Use existing libraries (which this answer covers)

There are some well established libraries out there that you can use

- [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library which is cross platform, written in C++
- [ZXing Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) is an Android port
- [Google Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview) API which is easier to use

Additionally, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711704/is-it-possible-to-use-camera2-with-google-vision-api) to gain more insight on using Camera2 with Mobile Vision.

Comment: Thanks @Suhel Chakraborty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure !
You have to use `BarcodeDetector`. Something like this :

```
open class BarcodeFragmentInternal : Fragment(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    protected var mSurfaceView: SurfaceView? = null

    protected var mScanListener: Listener? = null

    private var mCameraSource: CameraSource? = null

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Initialize Barcode Detector
        // Used to recognize barcodes like {@link Barcode.DATA_MATRIX} and {@link Barcode.QR_CODE}
        val mBarcodeDetector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(activity)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX or Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build()
        if (!mBarcodeDetector.isOperational) {
            sendError("NO_BARCODE_DETECTOR")
        }

        mBarcodeDetector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
            override fun release() {

            }

            override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
                if (detections != null && mScanListener != null) {
                    val detectedItems = detections.detectedItems
                    if (detectedItems != null) {
                        var i = 0
                        val size = detectedItems.size()
                        while (i < size) {
                            val barcode = detectedItems.valueAt(i)
                            mScanListener!!.onQRCodeAvailable(barcode.rawValue)
                            i++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        mCameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(context!!, mBarcodeDetector).build()

        mSurfaceView!!.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceCreated(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) {
                try {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity!!, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestCameraPermission()
                        return
                    }
                    mCameraSource!!.start(mSurfaceView!!.holder)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    sendError("NO_CAMERA_ACCESS")
                }

            }

            override fun surfaceChanged(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {

            }

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) {
                mCameraSource!!.stop()
            }
        })
    }


    private fun requestCameraPermission() {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ConfirmationDialog().show(childFragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG)
        } else {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.size != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                sendError("NOT_AUTHORIZED")

                view!!.post {
                    ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.request_permission))
                            .show(childFragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG)
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but you implementation for camera api 1 not camera 2 @Bruno

Comment: I'm using the [Google Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview)